# How to call parent's method from the child element/DOM/component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to call `closeBtn` method from `DrawerItem` DOM. Since it's a child component of `ToggleDrawer`, how can `DrawerItem` get access to `closeBtn` method?

```
class Header extends React.Component {
  //no method here

  render() {
    return (
      ...

      <ToggleDrawer
        icon_class="notify-toggle"
        alignment="right"
        icon_link={Url.urlForStatic('images.g')} ...
      >
        <DrawerItem text="Alert 1" />
        <DrawerItem text="Alert 2" />
        <DrawerItem text="Alert 3" />
      </ToggleDrawer>
```

This is ToggleDrawer class.

```
class ToggleDrawer extends React.PureComponent {

    ...
    closeDrawer() { //I want to call this method from DrawerItem.
                    //so that once user clicks the item, it closes the drawer.
        this.ref.hide();
    }
    ...
```

Here is DrawerItem

```
class DrawerItem extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props); // <- How can I get this.props.closeBtn method here?
    return (
      <div className="drawer-item">
        <BinaryLink to={this.props.link_to}>
          <span ...>{this.props.text}</span>
        </BinaryLink>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe should I would rather use MobX or Redux. But unfortunately, I can't use it this project. I can't touch `ToggleDrawer` class

Answer (score 0):

Simple way can do that is you should create closeDrawer prop for DrawerItem  and push **closeDrawer()** through the props of  **DrawerItem**

```
<ToggleDrawer
  icon_class="notify-toggle"
  alignment="right"
  icon_link={Url.urlForStatic('images.g')}...
>
  <DrawerItem closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer} text="Alert 1" />
  <DrawerItem closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer} text="Alert 2" />
  <DrawerItem closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer} text="Alert 3" />
</ToggleDrawer>;
```

Comment: There is no method in Header.jsx class, so we can't call this.closeDrawer method

Answer (score 0):

I think if you don't use Redux you should handle state, method outside ToggleDrawer. Why don't you make a component like ToggleDrawerContainer and deliver as props the method to DrawerItem.

```
class ToogleDrawerContainer extends React.Component {

    closeDrawer(){};
    <ToggleDrawer
        icon_class='notify-toggle'
        alignment='right'
        icon_link={Url.urlForStatic('images.g')}...
    >
        <DrawerItem closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer} text='Alert 1'/>
    </ToggleDrawer>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare toggleDrawer:ToggleDrawer

```
<ToggleDrawer
  ref={tg => {
    if (tg) this.toggleDrawer = tg;
  }}
  icon_class="notify-toggle"
  alignment="right"
  icon_link={Url.urlForStatic('images.g')} ...
>
  <DrawerItem
    closeDrawer={this.toggleDrawer ? this.toggleDrawer.closeDrawer : () => {}}
    text="Alert 1"
  />
  <DrawerItem
    closeDrawer={this.toggleDrawer ? this.toggleDrawer.closeDrawer : () => {}}
    text="Alert 1"
  />
  <DrawerItem
    closeDrawer={this.toggleDrawer ? this.toggleDrawer.closeDrawer : () => {}}
    text="Alert 1"
  />
</ToggleDrawer>;
```